# Problemas para editar dados do banco com php

Tags: php, msys2

Estou começando a estudar `hmtl5`, `css`, `java` e `php`, e junto com meus estudos estou desenvolvendo um portal, que será utilizado no meu trabalho, como uma passagem de turno e controle de problemas em andamento, até o momento, consegui criar o `form`, já consegui exibir os dados cadastrados em uma pagina resumido e em uma janela `modal completo`, agora estou tentando criar a parte de edição dos dados, já criei o o botão editar e o mesmo já está chamado a pagina de editar, porém o formulário aparece em branco, não estou conseguindo exibir os dados já cadastrados no form para poder editar e salvar.

Abaixo a página onde mostra o eventos cadastrados.

```
<?php include '_header.php';?>
<?php include '_menu.php';?>
<?php include '_footer.php';?>
<?php
    include 'conexaocti.php';

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM cti_evento";
    $con = mysqli_query( $conexao, $consulta )or die( mysqli_error );
    ?>

  <div class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <h1 class="page-header">Eventos CTI</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class=text-right>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="_novo_evento_cti">Novo Evento</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Chamado</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Série</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Peça</th>
            <th>RDM</th>
            <th>Aprovado</th>
            <th>Ação</th>
          </tr>
          <?php while ($dado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $dado["id"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo date("d/m", strtotime($dado["data"])); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $dado["nome"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $dado["chamado"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $dado["equipamento"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $dado["serie"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $dado["descricao"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $dado["peca"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $dado["rdm"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $dado["aprovacao"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong<?php echo $dado[" id "]; ?>">Visualizar</button>

              <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="_edita_evento_cti.php">Editar</a>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Excluir</button>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong<?php echo $dado[" id "]; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Eventos CTI</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p><b>Id do Evento:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["id"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <P><b>Data:</b>
                    <?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dado["data"])); ?>
                  </P>
                  <p><b>Nome:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["nome"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Chamado:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["chamado"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Equipamento:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["equipamento"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Série:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["serie"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Ambiente:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["ambiente"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Descrição do Problema:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["descricao"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Peça Pedida:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["peca"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Enviado Alerta:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["alerta"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Pedido de RDM:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["rdm"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Peça Entregue:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["entregue"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Impacto para o Cliente:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["impacto"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Aprovação de RDM:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["aprovacao"]; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><b>Observação:</b>
                    <?php echo $dado["observacao"]; ?>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <?php } ?>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Agora a página que estou tentando fazer editar:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>

<?php include '_header.php';?>
<?php include '_menu.php';?>
<?php include '_footer.php';?>

<div class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">Editar Eventos CTI</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form accept-charset="utf-8" name="cadastro_cti" class="form-control" action="salvar_edicao_cti.php" method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="data">Data:</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="data" name="data" placeholder="Insira a Data">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <select id="nome" class="form-control" name="nome">
            <option value="Selecione"> Selecione </option>
            <option value="Denis Augusto"> Denis Augusto </option>
            <option value="Emerson Carvalho"> Emerson Carvalho </option>
            <option value="Filipi Prado"> Filipi Prado </option>
            <option value="José Luciano"> José Luciano </option>
            <option value="Leonardo Fuzari"> Leonardo Fuzari </option>
            <option value="Marcos José"> Marcos José </option>
            <option value="Roberto Mota"> Roberto Mota </option>
            <option value="Vitor Pio"> Vitor Pio </option>
                        </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="chamado">Chamado:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chamado" name="chamado" placeholder="Número de Chamado">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="equipamento">Equipamento:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="equipamento" name="equipamento" placeholder="Tipo do Máquina">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="serie">Número de Série:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="serie" name="serie" placeholder="Digite a Série">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ambiente">Ambiente:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ambiente" name="ambiente" placeholder="Digite o Ambiente">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="descricao">Descrição do Problema:</label>
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="descricao" rows="3" maxlength="450" name="descricao" placeholder="Descreva o Problema."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="peca">Peça Pedida:</label>
            <select id="peca" class="form-control" name="peca">
            <option value="Selecione"> Selecione </option>
            <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
            <option value="Não"> Não </option>
            <option value="Sim - Saldo Zero"> Sim - Saldo Zero </option>
            <option value="Não - Saldo Zero"> Não - Saldo Zero </option>
                        </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="alerta">Enviado Alerta de Saldo:</label>
            <select id="alerta" class="form-control" name="alerta">
            <option value="Selecione"> Selecione </option>
            <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
            <option value="Não"> Não </option>
                        </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="rdm">Pedido de RDM:</label>
            <select id="rdm" class="form-control" name="rdm">
                            <option value="Selecione"> Selecione </option>
            <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
            <option value="Não"> Não </option>
                        </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="entregue">Peça no Local:</label>
            <select id="entregue" class="form-control" name="entregue">
            <option value="Selecione"> Selecione </option>
            <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
            <option value="Não"> Não </option>
                        </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="impacto">Impacto em Andamento:</label>
            <select id="impacto" class="form-control" name="impacto">
            <option value="Selecione"> Selecione </option>
            <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
            <option value="Não"> Não </option>
                        </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="aprovacao">RDM Aprovada:</label>
            <select id="aprovacao" class="form-control" name="aprovacao">
        <option value="Selecione"> Selecione </option>
        <option value="Sim"> Sim </option>
        <option value="Não"> Não </option>
                        </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="observacao">Observação Final:</label>
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="observacao" rows="3" maxlength="450" name="observacao" placeholder="Descreva a Observação."></textarea>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align: right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Por fim a página que irá salvar a edição.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
    <?php include '_header.php';?>
    <?php include '_menu.php';?>
    <?php include '_footer.php';?>
<?php

    include_once('conexaocti.php');

$data = $_POST['data'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$chamado = $_POST['chamado'];
$equipamento = $_POST['equipamento'];
$serie = $_POST['serie'];
$ambiente= $_POST['ambiente'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$peca = $_POST['peca'];
$alerta = $_POST['alerta'];
$rdm = $_POST['rdm'];
$entregue = $_POST['entregue'];
$impacto = $_POST['impacto'];
$aprovacao = $_POST['aprovacao'];
$observacao = $_POST['observacao'];


$cadastrado = ("UPDATE cti_evento SET data='$data', nome='$nome', chamado='$chamado', equipamento='$equipamento', serie='$serie', ambiente='$ambiente', descricao='$descricao', peca='$peca', alerta='$alerta', rdm='$rdm', entregue='$entregue', impacto='$impacto', aprovacao='$aprovacao', observacao='$observacao'");

mysqli_query($conexao,$cadastrado) or die("Erro ao tentar atualizar registro");
mysqli_query($conexao,"SET NAMES UTF8");
mysqli_close($conexao);
echo "Evento atualizado com sucesso!";
?>
```

Será que alguém pode me ajudar, a fazer aparecer o dados do form quando eu clico em editar e depois salvar essa edição?